# Uninstalling python versions, packages, paths to make it as it was from default Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, version

I am currently trying to install some of my software on the updated ubuntu 20.04
(I have updated 16.04->18.04->20.04). 
However, it looks like because I have not been respecting virtuanlenv / conda envs, I have tons of pythons installed and total mess with the packages. Thus, I guess a lot of paths/variables/libraries between different python version is somehow mixed and my software could 
not compile properly.

Is there any way to make python installation as it was coming with default 20.04 version?
Remove python versions I have installed, python libraries, set all paths/symlinks to what would be default in ubuntu 20.04?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is, but it depends on what you did to install all the various Python verisons. Please [edit] your question to add more information about those (for example, a list of the various interpreters you have, and specific build problems you’re running into).

Comment: I did a clean install of 20.04 and normally install all the same apps from previous install or 18.04. But this time I installed in groups and any that wanted python2, I did not install. If you have any older python2 apps, you still need python2. One or two apps I like are still only python2, but I will not install them. `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` only shows python3 on my system with config files.